# FB.getLoginStatus() not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to write a code that checks whether the user is logged in or not, 
and found that there is a built-in method in FBJS API, which is called getLoginStatus()

I have implemented it inside of html, 
but for some how, alert() inside of the getLoginStatus() is not fired.

I have also tried to add channelUrl at init(),but it still does the same.

Below is the code that I have written.

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- Initialize FB API for use -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    //var curLoc = window.location;
    //var chanURL = curLoc.protocol + "//" + curLoc.hostname + ":" + 
    //curLoc.port + "/channel.html"


        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '####', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});       

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                  if (response.session) {
                    // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                    alert('logged in');
                  } else {
                    // no user session available, someone you dont know
                    alert('not logged in');
                  }
            });
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script');
            e.type = 'text/javascript';
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
                '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            e.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
    </script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I had this the other day and the problem was that I was NOT logged in in Facebook AND my App was in Sandbox mode. Maaaaybe it's the same here, longshot but wanted to suggest it anyway.

Note: Comparable combinations that wouldn't work are being logged in in Facebook as a Test user that has no access to the application in question or being logged in in Facebook as a non-test/non-admin user AND having the app in sandbox mode.

Answer (score 5):

BTW. They changed it again.
It is now:

**response.authResponse**

and not **response.session** anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. I was caused by the 'Sandbox Mode' in the FB App settings. When enabled, it won't fire the getLoginStatus() response. Probably because it is unknown if you're actually a registered developer when not logged in.

Answer (score 2):

They changed it. Run console.log on response, and see you need to test as so:

```
if (response.status=='connected')) {...}
```

edit: here is most of my login:

```
<?php 
// using Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1)
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => APP_ID
  'secret' => SECRET
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
     // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
}
}
?>
```

and the js in the body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
      status  : true,
      cookie  : true, 
      oauth: true,
      channelUrl : MY_CHANNEL_URL,
      xfbml   : true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        console.log( response );
        if ((response.status)&&(response.status=='connected')) {
            loadStreamInto ( $("#FBmessages") );
        } else {

        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bobbi. I have changed the if statement to response.status, but still no response, I have used console.log as well, but it doesn't output any on firebug. I also have tried to use authResponse by enabling oauth, but same. Does it matter if I use localhost to test it?

Comment: FB will complain when you try to re-direct login if your path is wrong. I think you would notice that. I use localhost all the time, just enter that as your app site url on your developers page. RE console.log. If you get nothing, see if your fbAsyncInit is being called at all, debug from there.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you replaced you actual appId with #### in the code you linked.  If not, that is your problem.

Assuming you have actually placed your appId in here, it could be related to the fact that you are testing on localhost.  I believe that the javascript will not function if the url it is being served from does not match up with the url associated with the app for the given App Id

Answer (score 1):

the response.status=='connected' happens only if you put oauth:true in fb.init

code looks fine to me should work as is not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: thanks for the comment user911086. I also don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this would work for you, but I had a similar problem with my deployed app. It worked fine on my localhost but not when deployed to Heroku. I realised that in the Facebook App settings I had the urls all set as local ones - when I changed this to my deployed app url it fixed it.