# Facebook API - Detect if session is active OR NOT active

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm sure I'm simply overlooking something in the Facebook API docs. Basically, after I've loaded the FB Graph, I need to know if the session is active... I cannot simply assume they're logged out and simply re-render if they're logged in once the 'auth.statusChange' event is triggered. I need to know right off the bat.

Below is the code that I've used. Most importantly the FB.getLoginStatus/getAuthResponse/getAccessToken don't work like I'd expect; essentially where it indicates, when invoked, whether they're logged in or out.

```
(function(d) {

    // Create fb-root
    var fb_root = document.createElement('div');
        fb_root.id = "fb-root";
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild( fb_root );

    // Load FB Async
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);

    // App config-data
    var config = {
        appId : XXXX,
        cookie: true,
        status: true,
        frictionlessRequests: true
    };

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // This won't work.
        // I can't assume they're logged out and rely on this to tell me they're logged in.
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {});

        // Init
        FB.init(config);

        // These do not inidicate if the user is logged out :(
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { });
        FB.getAuthResponse(function(response) { });
        FB.getAccessToken(function(response) { });
    };

}(document));
```

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: `don't work like I'd expect` ? They work the way they should. What problems do you have with them ?

Comment: I need a method to either return Boolean if user is logged in, or return an object literal of session data (maybe with a status property) that indicates if logged in. Instead it seems the method is to initially assume the user is logged out and subscribe for the auth status change to notify you; which initially only notifies you if they're logged in, otherwise doesn't do anything. This the problem I'm experiencing where I need to know if they're logged in or out. I guess you could say I'm wanting to do this synchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, but I found the answer on another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765144/560686

Apparently, when you're still in Sandbox mode `FB.getLoginStatus()` will fire the callback only when they're logged in, but not when they're logged out. To get this to work, I had to Disable the Sandbox mode. :)